# How can a iOS user remove keychain after uninstalling app

Tags: ios, iphone, keychain

I Know that the keychain will be maintained even after an app is uninstalled.

However, is there a way to remove the keychain for users? Like, restore the whole phone.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no callback or method of removing the keychain items on deletion of your app, so there's no individual way to remove a single keychain item.

If you restored the entire phone to factory defaults Settings -> General -> Reset -> Erase All Contents and Settings, then it would be removed (along with everything on the phone!)

Comment: Yes, I dare not try erasing all contents and settings because all things are gone once I do it.